# Mock objects in Inspec

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

Is there a concept of mock-objects in Inspec? 
I want to mock a REST API, because the server providing this API is not available in my build pipeline.

Comment: Inspec is about testing infrastructure, not applications.

Answer (score 0):

InSpec is built on top of [RSpec](https://rspec.info/), which is a popular testing library in Ruby. Fortunately, RSpec supports many [forms of mocking](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs), including [Mocks and Stubs](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).

If you have some intermediate class that wraps this REST API functionality, say you call it `ServiceGateway`, then you can make a mock of that service in your InSpec tests with an RSpec `double` like so:

```
gateway = double('ServiceGateway')
expect(gateway).to receive(:get_data).and_return({ data: [1,2,3] })

# instantiate class under test providing the double to execute the rest of the test.
```

You should always check which version of RSpec the InSpec version you're using depends on. You can do this by looking at either your `Gemfile.lock` file or in RubyGems.org's transitive view. For example, [InSpec `4.18.104` depends on RSpec `3.9.0` transitively through the `inspec-core` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/inspec/versions/4.18.104/dependencies).

One final thought, if you're planning on interacting a bunch with REST APIs and want a more realistic representation of what they return for a more "end to end" style test (which InSpec ultimately is), consider pulling in the [`vcr` gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr). This gem performs record/playback of the API, making a real call the first time and using the saved results on subsequent tests. It does sometimes give you a false sense of security (it'll miss API changes), but it does give the full end to end experience.

Comment: I thought that InSpec replaces RSpec. All RSpec tests should be replaced by using InSpec.

Comment: Yes, but InSpec is built on top of RSpec, it's a superset. Anything you can do in RSpec you can do in InSpec.

Comment: To add further info to @ArthurMaltson 'superset' comment, Inspec adds extra resources that can be tested (cloud providers, os resources etc), and it adds metadata (impact, title, description, tags) which allow non-technical and/or governance users (such as CISO's) to understand the content.